# Pop animation is not working in first UINavigationController of UITabbarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I don't know what is wrong with my code. i have developed app successfully and all the things working fine except when i launch app first time, In side first navigation controller, the pop animation is not working fine. it seems that `Pop without animation`. and its working fine when i changed the tab and come back on first tab. and doing `push-pop` then its working fine.

I tried to figure out problem since week. but could't get success  because of lengthy code. I have tried the same animation with creating `Tabbar Demo` and its working fine.

My app has following hierarchy.

```
UINavigationController --> UIViewController --> UITabbarController --> Four UINavigationController --> UIViewControlle.
```

I have taken `UITabbarController` in  my `storyboard`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I know that i asked the question and also provide solution for same. I have asked this question long time ago and i am not getting any solution for this because there is illogical bugs. Not every `Tabbar` base application have same. Here i am adding solution that is result of long time debugging and i found that even single line can break your project.

Actually i have added `UITabbarController` from storyboard and programmatically created `UITabbarController` class and type cast it with `UITabbarController` inside `storyboard`.

Here my problem is, i forgot to write `[super viewDidAppear:animated];` inside `-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` method. so i will break pop animation first time then it will work fine.

After getting this solution, even i don't know how this line affect whole code. but i don't  want the other people to waste their time to find out such single line (unexpected issue) problem. so here i am adding this code.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
```

Comment: You are my hero! Thank you so much. I have been wasting too much time on this issue. But finally I fixed it. Thanks again :D

Comment: You are a genius, thank you! This issue was bothering me for quite a while, couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Thanks, Saved my day!

Comment: Seriously did not imagine this would cause such a trouble :(

Answer (score 0):

For **Swift 5**

Depending on [@Jatin Patel - JP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29984629/7715349) answer

Create custom class for your TabBarController

Add this Code in your UITabBarController file

```
class MyTabBarController: UITabBarController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
  }

  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
      super.viewDidAppear(animated)
   }
 }
```