# Corrupted navigation bar after navigating

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

This is the current situation:

```
UITabBarController
    UINavigationController
        UIPageViewController
            Some UIViewControllers (the actual content)
```

So the UIPageViewController contains some UIViewControllers, which all contain an UITableView.

[image: This is what the Apps looks like]

When I click one of the rows in the UITableView the UIViewController calls the didSelect method. The method looks like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    let activity = self.activities[indexPath.row - 1]
    self.delegate?.dayTableViewSelectedActivity(activity, sender: self)
}
```

Then the UIPageViewController has implemented the protocol so the delegate method is being called. The method looks like this:

```
func dayTableViewSelectedActivity(activity: Activity, sender: DayTableViewController) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("openDetails", sender: activity)
}
```

The App then navigates (pushes) to a DetailViewController. When I swipe back (default iOS behavior) the DetailViewController instantly pops to the UIPageViewController, without the animation. Then my navigation bar is broken, and contains a back button that doesn't belong there, because I can't go back any further.

[image: Broken navigation bar]

When I click a cell again the console gives me a `nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar` message. Every action I take from there gives me more console errors like:

```
nested pop animation can result in corrupted navigation bar
Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.
```

This error is frustrating me for hours now, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. There are no double segues. I checked it multiple times. I hope you guys can help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After struggling a few more hours, I've found the answer here: [Pop animation is not working in first UINavigationController of UITabbarController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29793713/pop-animation-is-not-working-in-first-uinavigationcontroller-of-uitabbarcontroll)

I was indeed having a subclass for my UITTabBarController that overrides the `viewDidAppear` method. I added `super.viewDidAppear` and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to want to make sure that when you navigate back to the PageViewController you use Unwind Segue. This will pop the TableViewController off the top of the stack and return you to the PageViewController. Here is a decent article about how to use it in Swift"

https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/12/18/working-with-unwind-segues-programmatically-in-swift/

Comment: Thanks! I will try this when I get home. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. In the tutorial they do an unwind segue programmatically. But I just want the default iOS behavior (that when you swipe right in a UINavigationController you go to the previous view controller)... So when I swipe right in my DetailViewController I want to go back to the UIPageViewController.